# ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined

Tags: javascript, mootools, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am developing  a joomla component. It is executing but giving

`ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined`

I check that default java scripts like `motool.js core.js` are not loading.

How can I load them automatically and not manually like `<script src=""></script>`?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
```

should load mootools.

If core is not loaded then run

```
JHtml::_('script', 'system/core.js', false, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

my problem was with `public $live_site` var in configuration.php. I didn't use `http://` prefix before it, so all links to scripts in admin panel looked like `http://mycoolsite.com/administartor/mycoolsite.com/media/system/js/script.js`

That's why Joomla Object was not loading. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
```

it will clear your joomla javascript error

Comment: Could you please explain more and clarify? This does not seem the answer to the question at first glance.